# What is the best way to extract specific text from a PDF using regex and Python?

Tags: python, pdf, text, extract

I have many pdf and I have to extract a certain sentence from that pdf, i read that pdf first 5 pages with python and converted them into string i want to extract only some information from there please help me

string is here:

```
Corrections: Nil, Deletions: Nil, Insertions: Nil, Overwriting: Nil,     AE(P)                                    EE 
 NIT No: 05/CE/CCD/2023-24 
 
Name of work: Construction of Academic Block (G+2) including Internal Electrical 
Installations, Lightning conductors, External LT service connection, DG set, Firefighting 
with down comer system, Automatic Fire alarm system, Lift, Solar PV system, VRF/VRV 
AC System,  LAN Networking, CCTV, IP based EPABX & Audio Visual system at Indian 
Institute of Handloom Technology at Salem, Tamilnadu. 
 
INDEX 
Sl. No Description Page No 
1 Cover page of the NIT 1 
2 Index 2-3 
3 Part-A (Cover page) 4 
4 Notice Inviting e-Tender (Press Notice) 5
```

Now I want to extract only whole **Name of work** from here till the end of line on Tamilnadu.
Please help me how to do it with regular expression or something else

I try extracting text sentence from string and want a certain information from that string

Comment: Using a regex is a good idea. Think about what characterises the beginning and end of the part you want to extract, and plug it in the expression. You will use "caturing group" to extract the text inbetween; see e.g. [here](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups).

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

`borb` comes with `RegularExpressionTextExtraction` which does exactly what you're asking for.

`RegularExpressionTextExtraction` implements `EventListener` and is notified of any event during rendering/parsing of the PDF.

For the purposes of your usecase, these events are things like "text has been rendered at location X, Y".

It keeps track of all these rendering events, organizes them by X,Y coordinates (since the standard allows a PDF document to render the page in any order it wants), and then attempts to match a regular expression against the text that would be drawn by those instructions.

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import RegularExpressionTextExtraction


def main():

    # read the Document
    # fmt: off
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    l: RegularExpressionTextExtraction = RegularExpressionTextExtraction("[lL]orem .* [dD]olor")
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])
    # fmt: on

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print matching groups
    for i, m in enumerate(l.get_matches()[0]):
        print("%d %s" % (i, m.group(0)))
        for r in m.get_bounding_boxes():
            print(
                "\t%f %f %f %f" % (r.get_x(), r.get_y(), r.get_width(), r.get_height())
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For more examples, check out [this link](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#53-extracting-text-using-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using PyMuPDF.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import sys

doc=fitz.open("input.pdf")
text=""
needle1 = "Name of work:"
needle2 = "Tamilnadu."

for page in doc:
    if page.number > 4:  # only read up to 5 pages
        break
    text += page.get_text()

p1 = text.find(needle1)
if p1 < 0:
    sys.exit(f"start string '{needle1}' not found.")
p2 = text.find(needle2, p1)
if p2 < 0:
    sys.exit(f"stop string '{needle2}' not found.")

print(f"Extracted text:\n{text[p1: p2+len(needle2)]}")
```

Comment: My position WRT using regular expressions for trivial cases like these: don't use a sledge hammer to crack a nut!